# Understanding jquery source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently started to delve deeper in to JavaScript and have come across this code construct in JQuery.

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
})(window)
```

Reading on stack overflow (and elsewhere) I have come to the conclusion that this is the same as

```
function foo(window, undefined) {
    ...
}

foo(window);
```

Am I correct in my assumption?
If so, what are the advantages of the former? (other than confusing newbs)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined

Comment: For the record, there is no jQuery in this code, it is just plain javascript.

Comment: I am trying to understand jquery; not using it but the actual jquery source, and that is where I saw this construct for the first time.

Comment: This and some other nice features from jQuery source: http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/

Comment: Looks like this question might have been edited after I and the others responded. But yes, you are correct that your 2 snippets are (almost) equivalent. Of course, in the second snippet, "foo" becomes a function that could be called again later -- so there is that obvious difference. And that is also the advantage of the former -- the coder of the 1st snippet wants to make it clear that this function is only called right here, right now.

Answer (score 22):

There are several things you need to know to make sense of it:

1. It is an anonymous function, which simply means it does not have a name.
2. The function is called immediately after it is declared. You see the open parenthesis on line 2, immediately after the function definition? That means, "call this function".
3. Only one parameter is passed to the function. That parameter is "window", which is the name of the global scope inside of a browser.
4. The function being called actually *expects* *2* parameters, but we're calling it with one. Javascript lets you call functions with more or fewer parameters than the function actually expects. There are ways of getting to the list of parameters that was passed.
5. Since we are only passing one parameter, the second parameter will automatically be set to "undefined". "undefined" is a special javascript value that means, get ready, "undefined".
6. It just so happens that we have also *named* our second parameter with the name "undefined". So in effect, we have created a local variable (parameters are very much like local variables) that is *named* undefined, and whose value is undefined.
7. Why on Earth did we do that? It is a way of ensuring that, within our anonymous function, if we refer to "undefined", it really will have the value of "undefined". If we didn't do that, and some crazy code outside of our scope redefined "undefined" (by saying something like "undefined = 42"), then we'd write code thinking we were referring to undefined but we'd actually be referring to 42. These shenanigans with passing 1 parameter but expecting 2, and calling the second one undefined, protects us from such nonsense.

I hope that's clear, let me know if it is not. I learned all that from Paul Irish's video mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

This is an anonymous function.  It is created and then goes out of scope, which here is the advantage.  It is created and instantiated immediately.  What is good about this is that it is not going to collide with any function on the global namespace, and thus will not obliterate anything you may have included on the page.

Comment: That makes sense, especially when combined with the link in the answer below and seeing the last few lines in jquery in that context.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anonymous function, it has quite a few benefits, like being only active in the current scope. [You can read more about it here.](http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/)