# Why does jQuery have undefined in its argument signature, and why does it pass window in again?

Tags: jquery

I see jQuery is wrapped with...

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
   ...
})(window);
```

[Source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

I see it passes in `window` again (my guess to make accessing it faster), but why is `undefined` there, and it is not passed in the self invoking function?

My guess is to protect jQuery from some bozo doing...

```
var undefined = 'defined';
```

[In that instance](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3TqWL/), `undefined` will be the string `'defined'`, and that is bad.

If I'm right (always a first :P), then it is a clever way of ensuring that `undefined` is *always* really `undefined`.

Am I right? Can anyone elaborate? Does passing `window` again indeed make things faster?

Thanks.