# What is meaning of "(function(window, undefined){})(window)" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)

```
(function(window, undefined){})(window);
```

What is the meaning of this code? I have seen it in many documents, especially in jQuery documents.

How does this work, and why is it defined thus?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined Will give you the answer to this question B-)

Comment: You might check out this other question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined

Answer (score 2):

You are scoping a piece of code..

By.

1. Defining it within an anonymous function `//function(){...}`
2. Executing it.  `//(function{})(args)`

Also, passing the window parameter allows for faster resolution of the meaning of that variable within your block of code.

Comment: Also known as a self-invoking function. It's used to prevent pollution of the global scope.