# explain pattern of rebinding globals to locals in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)

i see this pattern in the [jquery source code (line 13)](http://www.dustingetz.com/client-side-designer-templates/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js), where they rebind 'window' and 'undefined' to locals:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
     window.something = 42;
     var dummy = 42 === undefined;
}(window));
```

i think rebinding 'window' to a local is a strict mode thing (prevents accidental access to window) - but look at how they are binding `undefined` to a local as well. why?

Comment: That's an interesting block of code and I have no idea what it's doing.

Comment: Why not? After all, `window.undefined` _could_ change.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Setting `window.undefined = 400;` doesn't change `window.undefined` for some reason.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I dunno, I just tested it on the latest FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Blender IE7-9 on a blank page all let me overwrite `undefined`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Huh, that's odd

Comment: @Blender not really, if they all follow ES3 (which _is_ odd, especially for IE9).

Comment: @Blender I'm willing to do some testing with IE10 once it gets to W7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript you can assign a value to undefined, for example:

```
undefined=42;
```

The jQuery notation ensures that within the block undefined is really undefined.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

> Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5, undefined is non-writable, as per the ECMAScript 5 specification.

Comment: I think this should stick to the standard. The JS 1.8.5 reference if I am not wrong is a Mozilla thingy

Answer (score 1):

If someone somehwere changes `undefined` behavior of you code will be unpredicatbale:

```
 undefined = 42;
```

So you force `undefined` in your function to be always correct by not passing that argument during the call:

```
 function safe(undefined) {
   // undefined is really undefined here
 }

 function unsafe() {
   // undefined could be 42 here
 }

 undefined = 42;
 safe();
 unsafe();
```

Similar with `window`. Also passing `window` in give you additional adantage that you can test your function without actually impacting real window. I.e. your "mock" window can have custom `setTimeout` to test timing behavior of the function.

```
 function complex(window)
 {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000);
 } 

 var mockWindow = {setTimeout:...};
 complex(mockWindow);
 // here you can make sure setTimout was called and if necessary
 // call the callback.
```