# Underscore: meaning of '_:_'

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I´m looking a sample of a backbone / require.js app.

I have the following code:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  // Pull in the Collection module from above,
  'models/project/ProjectModel',
  'collections/projects/ProjectsCollection',
  'text!templates/projects/projectsListTemplate.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, ProjectModel, ProjectsCollection, projectsListTemplate){
  var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#projects-list"),

    render: function(){

      var data = {
        projects: this.collection.models,
        _: _ 
      };

      var compiledTemplate = _.template( projectsListTemplate, data );
      $("#projects-list").html( compiledTemplate ); 
    }
  });
  return ProjectListView;
});
```

Someone could explain me the meaning of the code bellow?

```
_: _
```

Comment: It's reference to underscore object passed to template arguments. Basically guys do this for perfomance reason and sometimes for resolve naming conflicts. It's quite similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined just assume that you pass _ or $ instead of window. As for me, it's a microoptimization and you will probably never see speed boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** They're assigning `_` a value of `_` in the `data` object. Just like `projects` is assigned `this.collection.models`.

**Longer answer:** By doing this you're creating a local reference to `_` so when the program is executed it doesn't have to look as far up the scope tree to find `_`. However, this really isn't needed as it most likely won't have any visible impact on performance.

The thing is there are a million other much larger bottlenecks so you'll most likely never notice the difference. For example, your example uses the `require.js` `test.js` plugin which loads external files on demand. However, that means before that text template can be used by your application it has to successfully complete a GET request. Which means the application probably has to wait anywhere from 10ms to 200ms before it can do anything with the template. So, any performance gains by using `_:_` are blown out of the water by that alone.