# Enhanced Javascript for-statement safe to use?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, abbreviation

Using the jQuery for-loop is quite slow, which is the reason why I'm considering using the regular for-statement more often. In order to have direct access to the current element, I found the following syntax (for regular arrays, not for objects of course):

```
for (var i = 0, e; e = array[i]; i++) { ... }
```

where `e` in the loop represents the current element.

*Is this syntax safe to use across all browsers?*

---

**Addition**

OK, I guess this could work, but it is not so useful anymore for a short notation:

```
for (var i = 0, e; (e = array[i]) !== void(0); i++) { ... }
```

Thank you all for answering!

Comment: You could test it here: http://tuttijs.com/ (and please share your results with us  :) )

Comment: As long as `array[i]` isn't a falsey value in the middle of the loop. And it depends on what you mean by "safe"

Comment: That's a combination of extremely basic language features.  It's guaranteed to work.

Comment: See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpwMt/) for what @Ian is talking about.

Comment: *"Is this syntax safe to use across all browsers?"* The **syntax** is safe. The loop isn't, barring certain assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend that. You see, if your array looks like this for example:

```
array = ["lala", 078, false, 992, "kas"];
```

Then your loop would only go through the first two, since the term `e = array[i];` would return false, because the third entry in the array is literally false.
This is better:

```
for (var i = 0, e; (e = array[i])===undefined; i++) { ... }
```

Make sure no one overwrites the undefined variable, e.g. by using a closure: [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined/)

Comment: Since it is really possible to overwrite `undefined`, if would probably best to use `(e = array[i]) !== void(0)`?

Comment: Btw: you probably meant `(e = array[i]) !== undefined`?

Comment: @SimonFerndriger You should be able to reliably check undefined with `typeof (e = array[i]) !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 7):

That is not a very good loop. Consider this array:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

It would stop on the first element because `0` is a falsey value. Same with

```
var array = ["foo", "bar", false, "hello"];
```

It would only get to `"foo"` and `"bar"`

---

Consider using this loop

```
for (var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++) { ... }
```

It works everywhere, only calculates `array.length` once, and is plenty performant.

---

Per T.J.'s comment, the scope of the args `i` and `len` above will exist your current function. So be careful that you don't make variable conflicts.

A somewhat common (but clunky) way of safeguarding against this is prefixing vars with `_`. Like this

```
for (var _i=0, _len=array.length; _i<_len; _i++) { ... }
```

Comment: Big +1. And in both (all) cases, remember that those variables are **not** scoped to the loop, but to the function. (ES6 will have `let` which will scope to the loop.)

Comment: Thanks for the review, T.J.. I gave you a shout-out in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As [naomik points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118425/157247), that form of loop will break if any of the array elements has a falsey value. Falsey values are `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, and `NaN`. So it would work, for instance, for an array of non-null object references. Not so much for an array of strings or numbers.

But if your question is about the *syntax*, then yes, it's "safe" in that it will work (and fail on falsey elements) in all JavaScript engines. The key bits you're relying on are:

1. That accessing the element beyond the end of the array (e.g., at `array[array.length]`) will give you a falsey value (`undefined`) rather than throwing an exception, and
2. That the result of an assignment expression (`e = array[i]`) is the value that was assigned.

Yes, both of those are reliable. (Well, #1 is reliable if the array really is a JavaScript array. Host-provided array-like objects may vary.)

---

In any case, note that neither `i` nor `e` is scoped only to the loop. ES6 will have `let`, which will be, but variables declared with `var` are scoped to the function they're in.