# Why should I reference jQuery in a self contained function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    . . .

})(jQuery);
```

I see this everywhere, but I don't understand why we're sending jQuery as a parameter in a self contained function. jQuery is already being referenced. Also, why are we defining `undefined` as a parameter?

Comment: You're passing it in so that inside you can use `$` without fear of some other library overriding it. looking for duplicate. the undefined portion helps with minification if you compare against undefined, otherwise i don't know

Comment: This answer will help in understanding why `undefined` is passed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined

Comment: Unless you're writing plugins or code that others might use, this isn't really neccessary if you have control over your project and know what goes where, but it does help a little with minification (the undefined argument). Note that it's not a DOM ready function, and `jQuery(function($) { ...` does the same thing with an added DOM ready handler

Comment: Sometimes the neighbors break things.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Passing `$` to the anonymous function ensures that the namespace is protected (i.e. does not conflict with other libraries that also use the `$` shortcut).

Oftentimes, `undefined` is passed to a function to ensure that the variable is truly `undefined`. For example, consider the following code exerpt:

```
undefined = '123';
if(myVar == undefined)
{
    // Will only ever execute if myVar == '123'
}
```

As noted in the comments though, unless you're writing a plugin or some such, using `jQuery(function($) {  })` is probably a better approach, since it protects the `$` shortcut and also provides a DOMReady event, meaning less code is required to achieve the same result.

If you need to check against `undefined`, you might also want to consider using [`$.noop()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop/).

Comment: What's the point of `$.noop()` for that? Sure an empty function returns `undefined`, but `void 0` is shorter and more efficient, and the intent is more clear (as the [void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) always returns `undefined`).

Comment: Yes, I agree. But my pointing out of `$.noop()` was simply a case in point that it's completely unnecessary when using jQuery to pass in `undefined`, you're right about the implications of it, though.

Comment: Nowadays, ES5-compliant browsers don't allow overwriting the global `undefined`. Anyway, even when considering older browsers, having the global `undefined` overwritten usually indicates some serious problem which shouldn't be allowed in a sane environment.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that `$` or `undefined` might have their values changed by subsequent code, eg. if you're mixing multiple JS libraries, or using multiple versions of a library.  By capturing your own copy of `$` and `undefined`, you guard against that.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    . . .

})(jQuery);
```

with that you'll be sure that $ is jQuery inside the function(whatever jQuery is in your script).
It doesnt prevent you from overwriting jQuery variable though,so use it only if you really need it( or you are creating a plugin and distributing a jquery plugin).

As for undefined,it will force undefined to actually be undefined,as undefined can be overwritten in some js engines.