# function expression has undefined passed in an IIFE

Tags: javascript

why would one have to pass undefined as an argument in the below referenced function

```
 var x = (function (window, undefined){
      function x(){
        this. result = 0;
      }
  })(window);
```

Comment: I think that is a bad idea taking *keyword* as parameter name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)

Comment: @Mritunjay: undefined isn't a keyword, its a variable.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure `undefined` references `undefined` and nothing else.