# passing a func decleration as argument

Tags: javascript, function, object

When wrapping code inside a function, i pass jQuery at the bottom and the $ sign as a parameter
to add it to the functions scope.

```
(function(window,$,undefined){


}(window, jQuery));
```

How can i do that with my own Objects?

I load my object in a separate script tag

```
function MyObj (){
}
```

So i guessed that all it takes is

```
(function(window,$,MyObj){

    var myObj = new MyObj();

}(window, jQuery, MyObj));
```

But MyObj is undefined.
I know i could wrap MyObj inside an IFI - but MyObj also needs some json-data that isnt there on page load...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As long as the separate script tag is BEFORE that IIFE that you've shown, then you shouldn't see that MyObj is undefined.

Comment: ... and "MyObj" must be declared at the global level - if the other script has all its code wrapped in a function like that, then "MyObj" won't be global.

Comment: what's the advantage of re-defining a variable that can be reached by the same name from inside the function?

Comment: @dandavis: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2716069/1048572)

Comment: If that were really the case, the function would not be `undefined`.

Comment: all good. it works now. sorry for stealing your time.

Comment: if this is supposed to be being done for performance, i doubt today's browsers will benefit. if performance is the only reason to do this, then it's probably not worth doing.