# Can't call function (window) {} with asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

How can I call that `addRect` function from asp.net c#

I tried this but it cannot call the function, what should I use ?

```
(function (window) {    
    function addRect(x, y, w, h, fill, flag, count) { }
})(window);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "addRect", "addRect(x,y,w,h,fill,flag,count);", true);
```

Comment: you can't directly call js function from js. how you call `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`?

Comment: also you define `addRect` in local scope, so you can't call it outside this scope

Comment: but data is getting from database thats why i use this

Comment: and also you you does not have global vars `x,y,w,h,fill,flag,count` when js try execute this function you get error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: [variable] is not defined`

Comment: if you have code in top post, you can't call function `addRect` in no way outside this scope

Comment: 'function addRect(x, y, w, h, fill, flag, count) {
        alert('t');
        var rect = new Box2;
        rect.x = x;
        rect.y = y;
        rect.w = w
        rect.h = h;
        rect.fill = fill;
        rect.flag = flag;
        rect.Count = count;
        boxes2.push(rect);
        boxes3.push(rect);
       

        invalidate();
    }'my fuction is like this

Comment: if this function wrap in self executed anonymous function like in your post: `(function(window){ ... })(window)` you can't call any function that defined inside

Comment: but its not call whats wrong in code?

Comment: you still not provide _how you call Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript_ i mean where placed this, when this called

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function myfunction(x) {
        alert(x)
    }
</script>
```

and from your code behind;

```
string myfunction= "myfunction(" + myvalue+ ")";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myfunction", myfunction, true);
```

Comment: could you take a look at this discussion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined maybe you will get your answer.