# How to minify/uglify document and window properties and methods

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

I'm looking for a way to minify a code like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerText = 'Hello World!';
}, 1000);
```

To something like this (minus spaces and new lines):

```
(function(a,b){
  a(function(){
    b('test').innerText='Hello World!';
  }, 1000);
})(setTimeout, document.getElementById)
```

using an automatic tool like UglifyJS or similar.
From the documentation it doesn't seem to be an option to do that.

**EDIT:**
It's quite common to see code like this:

```
(function (window, document, undefined) {
  // code here
})(window, document);
```

This is done for [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716188/2846401) and to [make the code more minifier-friendly](https://toddmotto.com/what-function-window-document-undefined-iife-really-means/#minifying), so I'm wondering why this is not done on a deeper level.

Comment: So wouldn't google be the place to look... not stackoverflow?

Comment: I couldn't find anything, if you have a link please share :)

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to do this in general, or asking about how to customise the minification performed by specific tools?

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) (tested it with version 3.14.5 but it should also work with version 2), you can use the `--enclose` option:

```
npx uglify-js --mangle --enclose setTimeout,document:setTimeout,document test.js --output test2.js
```

Giving the following output:

```
(function(e,t){e(function(){t.getElementById("test").innerText="Hello World!"},1e3)})(setTimeout,document);
```

Unfortunately it cannot replace expressions like `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **task runner**, or **module bundler** or **command line** to this:

- Task Runner

  - [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) with your [plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).
  - [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com) with your [plugin](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify).
- Module Bundler

  - [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) with your [plugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin).
- Command Line

  - [UglifyJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js).

And several other tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already know that stuff and it's not what I'm asking. The default options of UglifyJS don't "uglify" the code like I want

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear. I updated the question, do you understand what I mean now?