# Shadowing of global property 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jslint

Can anyone give me some pointers on fixing a warning I'm getting with JSLint.

I have the following code:

```
/* global window, define, module */
(function(global, factory) {
    var Gauge = factory(global);
    if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
      // AMD support
      define(function() {return Gauge;});
    }else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
      // CommonJS support
      module.exports = Gauge;
    }else {
      // We are probably running in the browser
      global.Gauge = Gauge;
    }
})(typeof window === "undefined" ? this : window, function(global, undefined) {
```

On the final line `(typeof window === "undefined" ...` I'm getting this warning:

```
Line 14: Shadowing of global property 'undefined' no-shadow-restricted-names
```

I'd like to get rid of this warning if possible.

Comment: I guess that the problem is that you are passing undefined to your function with alias factory and so you may potentially modify it, so that's why the no-shadow-restricted-names gives you a warning, you may try using function(global, factory = undefined) ...

Comment: Thank you @SilvioBiasiol thats fixed the warning.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll either want to drop the `undefined` parameter from [the `function(global, undefined) {` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2716069/1048572), or disable the warning on that particular line (since it guards against *other* scripts failing to heed this warning). Alternatively, use a build system to automatically prepend this UMD header to your modules, and run jslint only on the source.